# Issue with variable recognition

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

[image]

Why are the variables `r,s,u,v` identified differently in the definitions of `F2,G1,G2`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69957/discussion-on-question-by-navya-issue-with-variable-recognition).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem. Colors seem fine. Mac OS 10.13 Math v 11.2.

[image]

Here is the code. Do others have the same odd coloring as the OP?

```
F1[r_, u_] := f1[r] \[Theta]1[u];
F2[s_, v_] := f2[s] \[Theta]2[v];
G1[u_, r_] := g1[r] \[Theta]1[u];
G2[u_, r_] := g1[u] \[Theta]1[u];
```